# Simple Path via Javascript will not render

Tags: svg

Why doesn't this path render in any current browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="500px" height="500px"
        id="svgArea">
      <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
         var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
         var svgArea = document.getElementById ('svgArea');
         var spline = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "path");
         spline.setAttributeNS (svgNS, "d", "M0,300 C0,400 100,300 100,400");
         svgArea.appendChild(spline);
         ]]>
      </script>
   </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Yet if you inspect the DOM via firebug, you will see that the path was properly added to the svg area. Further, if you copy and past the generated SVG path declarative back into the html file and within the svg tags, the path renders.

I'm sure I am missing something embarrassingly simple.
Copy and paste the code yourself and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although elements are in the SVG namespace, attributes are not. So you want

```
spline.setAttribute("d", "M0,300 C0,400 100,300 100,400");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="500px" height="500px"
        id="svgArea">
      <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
         var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
         var svgArea = document.getElementById ('svgArea');
         var spline = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "path");
         spline.setAttribute("d", "M0,300 C0,400 100,300 100,400");
         svgArea.appendChild(spline);
         ]]>
      </script>
   </svg>
</body>
</html>
```